# Datepicker Calendar appears after refresh

Tags: php, datepicker

I have a column (called start_date) who appears the start date of vacation of an employee. This is an input who has default value the current date. A calendar (button) input exists near this input. When an user selects a date from this calendar this value saved in the db too. The values autosave through ajax without submit button. Also exists a button who adds new rows. My problem is  that needs to refresh the page in order to appears me the calendar and when I click the date from this the calendar disappear again. Also when click the add button the calendar re-disappers and in this case I refresh my page.
HTML code

```
<?php
$functions=new classes;
    $result=$functions->query("SELECT a.id as a_id,r.reason as id_reason,
    DATE_FORMAT(a.start_date ,'%d-%m-%Y') as start_date, a.duration as duration, a.notes as notes, st.name as id_status_adeia 
    FROM reason r, absent a,status_adeia st
    WHERE a.id_reason=r.id AND st.id=a.id_status_adeia AND a.id_proswpiko='$id'");

    $tabindex_counter=1;                
    echo "  
            <table class='main'>
                <tr class='main'>
                  <th class='main'>Reason</th><th class='main'>Start Date</th><th class='main'>Duration</th><th class='main'>Notes</th><th class='main'>Status</th><th class='main'>Delete</th>
                </tr>";



    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){      

            echo "<tr class='main'>";   
        foreach ($row as $key=>$val) {


            if ($key!="a_id") {
                if ($key=="id_reason") {

                    echo "<td class='main'><select id='".$row['a_id']."_$key' class='absent_edit' tabindex='$tabindex_counter' onchange='paint_select_yellow(this)' onkeypress='focus_next_input(this,event)' onblur='update_record (event,this,&quot;absent&quot;,&quot;$key&quot;,&quot;id&quot;,&quot;".$row['a_id']."&quot;)'>";$functions->options_list("SELECT id,name FROM reason",$val,false);echo"</select></td>";
                    $tabindex_counter++;
                }
                elseif ($key=="id_status_adeia") {
                    echo "<td class='main'><select class='absent_edit' id='".$row['a_id']."_$key' tabindex='$tabindex_counter' onchange='paint_select_yellow(this)' onkeypress='focus_next_input(this,event)' onblur='update_record(event,this,&quot;absent&quot;,&quot;$key&quot;,&quot;id&quot;,&quot;".$row['a_id']."&quot;)' ".$_SESSION['disabled'].">";$functions->options_list("SELECT id,name from status_adeia",$row['id_status_adeia'],false);echo"</select></td>";
                    $tabindex_counter++;
                }
                elseif ($key=="start_date") {

                    echo "<td class='main'><input disabled id='".$row['a_id']."_$key' class='absent_edit datepicker' tabindex='$tabindex_counter'  onclick='update_record(event,this,&quot;absent&quot;,&quot;$key&quot;,&quot;id&quot;,&quot;".$row['a_id']."&quot;)' value='$val'></td>";
                    $tabindex_counter++;
                    else {

                    echo "<td class='main'><input id='".$row['a_id']."_$key' class='absent_edit' tabindex='$tabindex_counter' onkeypress='focus_next_input(this,event)' onblur='update_record(event,this,&quot;absent&quot;,&quot;$key&quot;,&quot;id&quot;,&quot;".$row['a_id']."&quot;)' type='text' value='$val'></td>";
                    $tabindex_counter++;
                }
            }
            }
                echo "  <td class='main'><button class='button4' onclick='delete_record(&quot;absent&quot;,&quot;".$row['a_id']."&quot;)'><img src='delete.png' width='20' height='20'></button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";



    }
    echo "</table>";
        echo "<br/>";
    echo "<button class='button4' onclick='new_record_absent(&quot;$id&quot;)' value='ADD'/><img src='add.png' width='40' height='40'></button>";
    ?>
```

This is the code which update my records:

```
function update_record (evt,elem,table,field,check_field,check_var) {   

    if (elem.tagName=="INPUT") {

        elem.value=capitalizeFirstLetter(elem.value);

    }

    document.getElementById('test_texts').innerHTML='worked';
    var elem_id=elem.id;//store id to find the elem later in case a screen refresh has happened.
    var val=elem.value;
    if (field=="start_date" || field=="end_date") {

        var date_split=elem.value.split('-');
        val=date_split[2]+"-"+date_split[1]+"-"+date_split[0];


    }       


    if (elem.style.backgroundColor=="yellow") {//update only if there has been a change
        loadXMLDoc("/staff/update_record.php?table="+encodeURIComponent(table)+"&field="+encodeURIComponent(field)+"&val="+encodeURIComponent(val)+"&check_field="+encodeURIComponent(check_field)+"&check_var="+encodeURIComponent(check_var),function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){


                document.getElementById(elem_id).style.backgroundColor="lightgreen";
                document.getElementById('test_texts').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;


            }

        })
    }
}
```

Any suggestions of how do I solve this?  For some reason when I click add button or update the date ajax dont regognize the datepicker part

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this problem namely how to appear datepicker icon  without refresh?

Comment: I want to find a way to hold datepicker constant without refresh my page