# Datepicker button disappear after new entry

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have a form that automatically saves data through ajax. 
Especially I have a column (called start_date) who appears the start date of vacation of an employee. This is an input who has default value the current date. A calendar (button) input exists near this input. When an user selects a date from this calendar this value saved in the db too. The values autosave through ajax without submit button. Also exists a button who adds new rows. My problem is that needs to refresh the page in order to appears me the calendar and when I click the date from this the calendar disappear again.
I use this code for datepicker:

```
function onDOMReady(fn,ctx){var ready,timer;var onStateChange=function(e){if(e&&e.type=="DOMContentLoaded"){fireDOMReady()}else if(e&&e.type=="load"){fireDOMReady()}else if(document.readyState){if((/loaded|complete/).test(document.readyState)){fireDOMReady()}else if(!!document.documentElement.doScroll){try{ready||document.documentElement.doScroll('left')}catch(e){return}fireDOMReady()}}};var fireDOMReady=function(){if(!ready){ready=true;fn.call(ctx||window);if(document.removeEventListener)document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",onStateChange,false);document.onreadystatechange=null;window.onload=null;clearInterval(timer);timer=null}};if(document.addEventListener)document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",onStateChange,false);document.onreadystatechange=onStateChange;timer=setInterval(onStateChange,5);window.onload=onStateChange};

// This is called when the page loads, it searches for inputs where the class is 'datepicker'
onDOMReady(function(){

  // Search for elements by class
  var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i=0; i<allElements.length; i++) {
    var className = allElements[i].className;
    if (className=='datepicker' || className.indexOf('datepicker ') != -1 || className.indexOf(' datepicker') != -1) {
      // Found one! Now lets add a datepicker next to it  
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href='#';
      a.className="datepickershow";
      a.setAttribute('onclick','return showDatePicker("' + allElements[i].id + '")');
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src='calendar.png';
      img.style.height='17px';
      img.style.width='17px';      
      img.title='Show calendar';
      a.appendChild(img);
      insertAfter(a, allElements[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

Ajax code:

```
function update_record (evt,elem,table,field,check_field,check_var) {   

    if (elem.tagName=="INPUT") {

        elem.value=capitalizeFirstLetter(elem.value);

    }

    document.getElementById('test_texts').innerHTML='worked';
    var elem_id=elem.id;//store id to find the elem later in case a screen refresh has happened.
    var val=elem.value;
    if (field=="start_date" || field=="end_date") {

        var date_split=elem.value.split('-');
        val=date_split[2]+"-"+date_split[1]+"-"+date_split[0];


    }       


    if (elem.style.backgroundColor=="yellow") {//update only if there has been a change
        loadXMLDoc("/prosopiko/update_record.php?table="+encodeURIComponent(table)+"&field="+encodeURIComponent(field)+"&val="+encodeURIComponent(val)+"&check_field="+encodeURIComponent(check_field)+"&check_var="+encodeURIComponent(check_var),function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

                if (table=='posto') {

                    document.getElementById('kathikoda_edit').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

                }
                document.getElementById(elem_id).style.backgroundColor="lightgreen";
                document.getElementById('test_texts').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;




            }

        })
    }
}
```

Also this link  [Datepicker Calendar appears after refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003005/datepicker-calendar-appears-after-refresh). Any suggestion about how to keep datepicker button constant?

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this problem namely how to appear datepicker icon  without refresh?

Comment: Does anyone know a way to solve this?